# Trouble with os.popen

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

I'm learning Python with the *Think Python*. The problem I ran into is when I try the code in the example:

```
import os
cmd = 'ls -l'
fp = os.popen(cmd)
res = fp.read()
stat = fp.close()
print res
```

However, `print res` only returns an empty string where it should display the contents of the current directory in long format. `print stat` returns `1` indicating that something went wrong in the process, but there is no error message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are trying this in linux right? just asking.

Comment: from [`os.popen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen): _Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section._

Comment: Thanks everyone. I didn't expect my question to be answered so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you work on a windows system. If replace 'ls -l' by 'dir' than it should work on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, is just that you are working on a windows sistem.
I corrected your code:

```
import os

cmd = 'dir'
fp = os.popen(cmd)
res = fp.read()
stat = fp.close()
print res
print stat
```

Answer (score 0):

It should works in Python 2.7 (at least).

Anyway, it does not answer why it didn't works (but I think it's not a Python or `os.popen()` issue, but another more meta-thing) but, from [`os.popen() doc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen):

> **Deprecated since version 2.6**: This function is obsolete. Use the
>   [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with
>   the subprocess Module section.

---

If you are using Windows use `dir` instead of `ls`